# xhtml2pdf is creating URL with WinAnsiEncoding in Django

Tags: django

I am clicking a button and calling the django class and getting response in ajax success(function(data))

ajax

```
$('.contract-download').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'{% url 'app:contract' %}',
            method:'GET',
            data:{
            'data-invoice':$(this).attr('data-invoice'),
            'data-order':$(this).attr('data-order')

            },
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
            window.open("data:application/pdf,charset=utf-8" + escape(data))

            }
        })
    })
```

the new window it is creating its url is simply in WinAnsiEncoding

```
%PDF-1.4
%���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<<
/F1 2 0 R /F2 4 0 R /F3 8 0 R /F4 10 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/BitsPerComponent 1 /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode ] /Height 23 /Length 223 /Subtype /Image 
  /Type /XObject /Width 24
>>
stream

            003B00 002700 002480 0E4940 114920 14B220 3CB650
            75FE88 17FF8C 175F14 1C07E2 3803C4 703182 F8EDFC
            B2BBC2 BB6F84 31BFC2 18EA3C 0E3E00 07FC00 03F800
            1E1800 1FF800>
            endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/BaseFont /Helvetica-Bold /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F2 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Contents 24 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.2756 841.8898 ] /Parent 23 0 R /Resources <<
/Font 1 0 R /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] /XObject <<
/FormXob.c7485dcc8d256a6f197ed7802687f252 3 0 R
>>
>> /Rotate 0 /Trans <<

>> 
  /…
```

I want to give simple human readable url name here, how to do so?

Comment: What do you mean with "simple human readable url name"? You're opening a window with a data: URL, you can't change that.

Comment: @AKX sorry I could not explain Properly. actually all the above data is  being rendered in Url and only working on Firefox but not on Chrome

Answer (score -1):

use **link_callback** function

add font file(ex .ttf) in your static dir

and add encoding='utf-8' creating pdf

```
status = pisa.CreatePDF(
    html, dest=response,
    link_callback=link_callback,
    encoding="UTF-8"
)
```

I used refer to
[using-xhtml2pdf-in-django](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django)